# How to compile with gcc in php?

Tags: php, c, laravel, gcc

I'm trying to compile *.c file using shell_exec(gcc -o code.c code);
when I die dump I get that gcc is not recognized as a command but I do have it installed on my command. I can do shell_exec('ls') I also have the gcc path set I cain't think of anything else. can you? thanks ahead !

Comment: Can you call gcc with full absolute path?

Comment: Aside: `gcc -o code.c code` seems strange, shouldn't it be `gcc -o code.exe code.c` or `gcc -o code code.c` ?

Comment: I smell a deeeep security hole being dug.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Sounds interesting, please elaborate. Do you think of a php script which compiles uploaded free text to executables and then maybe even executes them?

Comment: @Yunnosch Compiling arbitrary code via PHP is implying it is going to be run via PHP. Shall I continue?

Comment: Just hope you don't use this to let people upload code to your server. You'll get hacked in seconds.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I totally agree, after spotting it with some second latency... ;-)

Comment: @David Can you convince us, or more importantly yourself, that this is not the extreme security risk forshadowed in the comments? I wonder if a question describing the idea should be considered the opposite of useful: destructive like a do-it-yourself manual for shooting the own foot.

Comment: C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe it was the absolute path i got errors and compilation ended message ! I was using gitbash so I didn't have the correct path being represented when I typed pwd, thanks @Yunnosch ! I definitly thought about the security being compromised if the file were uploaded and executed on the server thanks for confirmation. And my main idea is to have this script https://github.com/jzck/42-correction-jhalford, it's a correction script for c projects from 42 executed from a web app pulling the repo from git and saving the result in database. Thanks for all your answers !

Comment: Could you please make an answer yourself (that is perfectly acceptable here). I would like to get this out of the list of unanswered questions. Alternatively deleting the question serves the same purpose, but your problem and solution (though I do not 100% get it yet) seems actually useful. If you can extend your question to contain the relevant information and the answer to relate to them and explain the solution, I could imagine some upvotes coming in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please bear in mind at the moment I'm getting errors but gcc is actually compiling from a php function call in the web browser.

2>&1 means redirect stderr to stdout this link helped hope it can help you http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial.

```
    function compile()
    {
       $output = shell_exec("C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -o  $code  2>&1");

       dd($output);
    }



gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files\n
compilation terminated.\n
```

I can now use gcc with php shell_exec() function the errors I'm getting are now a simple understanding of the absolute paths my files have and making the correct gcc command to compile, the next step once I have actually managed to compile the code.c in .a.out will be to execute the .a.out file. I will share updates here once it is accomplished. Thanks for your help.