# How to execute clang with php

Tags: php, linux, bash

Tried

```
shell_exec("clang main.c 2>&1");
```

clang: error: unable to execute command: Executable "ld" doesn't exist!
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

```
exec("PATH=/bin");
```

not working

Also tried
[How to compile with gcc in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47401804/how-to-compile-with-gcc-in-php)

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/compiling-c-prog-using-gcc-in-php-234619/
not working either

Answer (score 0):

Your need use shell execute and make sh file with the action.

```
echo shell_exec('sh /home/scripts/action.sh');
```

action.sh

```
clang main.c
```

Comment: Is there any way to execute command directly with php ?

Comment: I only know this way, used for multiple task and works fine.